# <form> tag not included in first <tr> row of <s:iterator> in .jsp

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, struts2

I am working on Java webapp in the Struts framework. When I iterate over a list of reports (see code below), it embeds the "preview" button in a form with id="doDisplayPDF" in every row except the first row.
(java)

```
<s:iterator var="counter"  value="reports" status="key">
     <tr  id="row_<s:property value="repId"/>"
         class="">
          <td>  
            <input type="radio" id="<s:property value="repId"/>" name="reportsAvaiable" 
                 value="<s:property value="repId"/>" onclick="validate(this.id)"  />
              <s:property value="RepName"></s:property>
          </td>
    <td>
        <s:property value="template"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${not empty template}">
                    <s:form id="doDisplayPDF" theme="simple" target="_blank" action="doDisplayPDF">
                      <s:hidden name="fullFileName" value="%{reportDesinationPath + template}" />
                      <s:submit type="button" cssClass="btn btn-warning" cssStyle="height:auto;" value="Preview" onmouseover="style.cursor='pointer'" />
                    </s:form>              
            </c:when>
             <c:otherwise>N/A</c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </td>  
    <td> 
        <s:file name="upload" label="Report Name" tooltip="Choose PDF to upload" 
                accept=".pdf" required="true"
                cssClass="form-control" cssStyle="height:auto;" />
    </td>                                     
    <td>                                        
        <s:submit type="button" cssClass="btn btn-success" cssStyle="height:auto;" label="Upload For Delivery" value="submit"/>
    </td>
</tr>
 </s:iterator>
```

So the html output looks like this (without the  tag around the first , but it is after every subsequent row in the reports list...:

```
     <td>
        <input id="5090" name="reportsAvaiable" value="5090" onclick="validate(this.id)" type="radio">
           pdfnamesecret1
      </td>
        <td>
            pdfnamesecret1.pdf
        </td>   

                  <input name="fullFileName" value="pdfnamesecret1.pdf" id="doDisplayPDF_fullFileName" type="hidden">
                  <button type="submit" id="doDisplayPDF_0" value="Preview" class="btn btn-warning" style="height: auto; cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="style.cursor='pointer'">
                    Preview
                    </button>
    </td>  
    <td> 
        <input name="upload" value="" accept=".pdf" id="f_1_upload" class="form-control" style="height:auto;" type="file">
    </td>                                     
    <td>                                        
        <button type="submit" id="f_1_0" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="height:auto;">
            Upload For Delivery
            </button>

    </td>
</tr>

     <tr id="row_5073" class="">
          <td>  
            <input id="5073" name="reportsAvaiable" value="5073" onclick="validate(this.id)" type="radio">
              pdfnamesecret2
          </td>
    <td>
        pdfnamesecret2.pdf
    </td>
    <td>


                <form id="doDisplayPDF" name="doDisplayPDF" action="/report-admin/doDisplayPDF.action" target="_blank" method="post">
                  <input name="fullFileName" value="pdfnamesecret2.pdf" id="doDisplayPDF_fullFileName" type="hidden">
                  <button type="submit" id="doDisplayPDF_0" value="Preview" class="btn btn-warning" style="height: auto; cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="style.cursor='pointer'">
                    Preview
                    </button>

                </form>

    </td>  
    <td> 
        <input name="upload" value="" accept=".pdf" id="f_1_upload" class="form-control" style="height:auto;" type="file">
    </td>                                     
    <td>                                        
        <button type="submit" id="f_1_2" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="height:auto;">
        Upload For Delivery
        </button>

    </td>
</tr>
```

EDIT: Taking into consideration Andrea Ligios' considerations!

I have found a way to submit the action that I want by not nesting my form (still unsure why the first row was the only row to not have a nested form in the output).

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty template}">
<input type="button" cssClass="btn btn-warning clickable" cssStyle="height:auto;" value="Preview" onclick="submitForm2('<s:property value="%{reportDesinationPath + template}"/>');" />
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>N/A</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Which then calls a javascript function that submits a form with hidden params at the bottom of the .jsp:

Javascript function:
    function submitForm2(_filepath){
                   document.getElementById("selectedReportToPreview").value=_filepath;
                   document.getElementById('f_2').submit();
                }
Second form (Not nested):

```
<s:form theme="simple" action="doDisplayPDF" id="f_2" name="f_2">
<s:hidden name="fullFileName" value="%{reportDesinationPath + template}" id="selectedReportToPreview" />
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some considerations:

1. Never nest forms. Since you are using fields and a submit button (the outer one), I assume all the table itself is inside a form. Since you are creating a form inside a td, you would have nested forms, that is invalid and not working. Otherwise, you will have nothing to submit with the outer `s:submit` button;
2. Never assign the same id twice in a page; it is invalid HTML, and it won't work when using an ID selector;
3. Avoid mixing Struts Tags with JSTL when there is no need. Use `<s:if>` and `<s:else>` instead of `<c:when>` and `<c:otherwise>`;
4. Try using Struts tags whenever possible. Your `<input type="radio">` with two `<s:property/>` inside could easily become a less verbose, more readable `<s:radio>`. The `<form>` an `<s:form>`;
5. Remove the noise to get a better signal: `class=""` should be removed, for example;
6. Prefer CSS to inline styling, and prefer CSS to javascript for presentational purposes:

   ```
   cssClass = "btn btn-warning" 
   cssStyle = "height:auto;" 
   onmouseover = "style.cursor='pointer'"
   ```

   can be translated to

   ```
   cssClass = "btn btn-warning clickable"
   ```

   and in CSS file:

   ```
   .clickable {
       cursor : pointer;
       height : auto;
   }
   ```

   so you will be able to change it on-the-fly in the future, without the need to redeploy the whole project to change a naive setting like `height : auto`.

Comment: So it seems that I'm having issues with your point one. I'm not sure how I'm going to invoke my action without nesting a form. I want the user to "preview" the report using a preview button which calls the doDisplayPDF action. I agree with your points on simplifying the css!

Comment: 1st point is FATAL, 2nd is ERROR, the others just WARNING :) If you need to call an action from an s:submit button that is not the form's one, use `<s:submit action="aDifferentAction"/>`; (note that from struts 2.3.15.3 up, you need to enable a param in struts.xml to enable action prefix;). Please remember to accept the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: Thanks Andrea, I have edited my initial post to show you what I did to work around the nested forms. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the buttons have the id "doDisplayPDF_0" whenever they are under the  with id "doDisplayPDF". 
Because of your code here:

```
<s:form id="doDisplayPDF" theme="simple" target="_blank" action="doDisplayPDF">
    <s:hidden name="fullFileName" value="%{reportDesinationPath + template}" />
    <s:submit type="button" cssClass="btn btn-warning" cssStyle="height:auto;" value="Preview" onmouseover="style.cursor='pointer'" />
</s:form>
```

The other button is not under this form so they have a different ID then.

Not sure if this answers your question.